# PHP MySQL dont get last selected

Tags: php, mysql

i have a mysql Table with some rows.

The Select gets one (LIMIT 1) row. After a counter it reloads and get random another row. But sometimes he get the same (cause random).

How can i setup that he dont get the last row?
The problem is, i cannot do that in mysql. I must do that in the SESSION or only on that site.

I tried that:

```
    $_SESSION['ads'] .= ','.$adid;
```

put that adid in "ads" SESSION and read it before SELECT here

```
session_start();
$ads = substr($_SESSION['ads'], 1);
$ads = str_replace(",", "','", $_SESSION['ads']);
```

In the SELECT is that

```
AND id NOT IN ('".$ads."')
```

But sometimes, i dont know why, he save two items or something... i dont find out why, cause the SELECT is LIMIT 1

Any ideas how to do that or is there a mysql function?

For any reason, the script is load two times the SELECT or something
This is the code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $adid = $row["id"];
    $_SESSION['ads'][] = $adid;
}
echo 'adid: '. $adid;
print_r($_SESSION['ads']);
```

There he print like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 3
)
```

I dont know, why he puts 2 in there. Cause the echo of the $adid shows only one!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this maybe :

**1/ Create a new session and create an empty array :**

```
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['ads']))
    $_SESSION['ads'] = array();
```

**2/ Do you select and add the id in this array :**

```
if (empty($_SESSION['ads']) {
    // 1. Do your select with no where condition 

    // 2. Fetch the result
    $data = /* result of the select */;

    // 3. Add the selected id in your session array
    $_SESSION['ads'][] = $data['id'];

} else {
    // 1. Do your select but with a WHERE condition
    $query = "SELECT...
              WHERE id NOT IN ( " . implode( "', '" , $_SESSION['ads'] ) . " )";

    // 2. Fetch the result
    $data = /* result of the select */;

    // 3. Add the selected id in your session array
    $_SESSION['ads'][] = $data['id'];

}
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thats look like what i need, but i get this error: `syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE)` in nginx on line `$_SESSION['ads'] = array();`

Comment: I forgot a `)` in the if condition ! My bad

Comment: Yeah i found that also. But its same problem :( 
First reload it shows 1 in the array, but than it put 2 at same time in... :/ I dont find out why...

Cause its only the SELECT, than while in row with only 1 ITEM (LIMIT 1 in SELECT)... i dont know where he find the other number. Can i contact you anywhere? Than i can send you a link that you can see it

Comment: Just edit your question to understand the problem : 1/ add your the select part (query + how you fetch result + what is this result) 2/ add what you got if the session variable to understand what doesn't works !

Comment: @txen I have an other question btw : you want to "NOT GET" only the last row you select OR all the last rows? For example : in database you have row 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. If you select 1 first -> next you can select 2, 3, 4, 5. Then you select 2, what happen? You can only select 3, 4, 5 because you selected 1 first then 2 OR you can select 1, 3, 4, 5 because you don't want only the last row?

Comment: i tried a little bit and i am confused... thats the select now `$query = "SELECT * FROM ads LIMIT 1;";` for testing. And than comes while $row with fetch_assoc and there the session, but i dont know why, he adds the id two times

Comment: I want to get random LIMIT BY 1 from SELECT, where NOT in the array. So, if i have 1 and 2 in Array, i dont want to get 1 or 2, i want to get another than 1 or 2. Like ID 3, 4 or something. But everytime only one

Comment: @txen you didn't anwser my question :) And please add the detail in the question, no in the comment part it's hard to read ! I need the full logic of you code and see what you really do to find the problem

Comment: @txen You still don't anwser my question about what you want : only remove the last id OR all the last id? And about the 2 id in the session array : it's because you make 2 select? Each time you will do a new select you will add an id if you don't empty the array...so anwser my question to understand what you really want and solve this problem please :)

Comment: I will get ONE (LIMIT 1) where is not in the array list. When ID is in Array, i dont want get that.

I think your code works, but i read that chrome has bugs or something... cause any reason the site loads two times not one time

I also see in nginx log 2 times loading, but i dont know why chrome loads 2 times

Comment: I understood the LIMIT 1...it's not my question ! Each select = 1 row = 1 id selected = 1 id add to the `$_SESSION['ads']` array. So every time you make a select, your `$_SESSION['ads']` will add a new value : this is what you want or not? The fact that you get multiple value in `$_SESSION['ads']` is normal if you make multiple select with no reset of your `$_SESSION` array